# Makefile with Jar and Package Dependencies

Tags: java, makefile, dependencies, package, javac

I have been trying all day to get this thing to work. Basically I need to create a makefile to build my project from its sources. I know a little about Linux but not much and I am a complete makefile newbie.

I have tried loads of examples from all over the net and all complain that they are missing dependencies. Others have suggested using Ant or Mavern but this is not possible the precise handin notice is:

> **Quoted from Specification**
>
> Your submission should consist of a
>   single file comp2010.tar suitable for
>   use on a Linux  system. This must
>   contain a file Makefile, and all
>   sources. You should not hand in any
>   .class files. Your Makefile must build
>   the tool from the Java sources. The
>   main class must be called Blaise. In
>   short, the (automatic) testing process
>   will consist of:
>
> `tar xf comp2010.tar`
>
> `make`
>
> `java Blaise < test.file > testout 2>
>   testerr`
>
> These commands will be executed in an
>   empty directory in a standard
>   departmental teaching  Linux
>   environment with Java 1.6. The
>   CLASSPATH will include the ANTLR jar,
>   version 3.2.
>
> NOTE: Please ensure that your
>   submission can be compiled and
>   executed on standard  departmental
>   machines. Please make sure that you
>   use the right version of Java, and
>   that you do not use absolute paths. If
>   you use any external libraries, you
>   need to submit these as well.

So you see I cannot set up any environment variables as the machine to run it is not mine and I am not allowed administrative access. I cannot hand in any class files so the makefile is not for me and Ant / Mavern scripts will not work because the testing procedure is automated and uses this makefile and all I am allowed to hand in is .java files. So I need to build a makefile there is no way around that.

The source structure is as follows:

> src\Package1*.java
>
> src\Package2*.java
>
> auto-generated\PackageA*.java

There are source files in all 3 folders needed for the thing to compile. The Main() method is in src\Package1\1.java

Each of these directories is a package in Eclipse and these 3 packages depend on each other as well as an external Jar file antlr-3.2.jar

---

So How do I make this makefile. That is my question and I have provided my own attempt below:

---

```
JAVAC = javac
CLASS_FILES = src/package1/1.class auto-generated/packageA/2.class auto-generated/packageA/3.class auto-generated/packageA/4.class src/Package2/5.class src/Package2/6.class src/Package2/7.class src/Package2/8.class src/Package2/9.class src/Package2/10.class src/Package2/11.class src/Package2/12.class antlr-3.2.jar.*

Default: $(CLASS_FILES)

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) $<

clean: $(RM) *.class
```

---

This fails with errors like "org.antlr.runtime does not exist" this is inside the antlr-3.2.jar. I am at my wits end and need to hand in soon. I assume I am simply importing the jar all wrong and maybe I need to use whatever CLASSPATH is. Im sorry if this is a simple question but I have been trying for 6 solid hours now to make one of these. Any help you could give would be most appreciated.

Kind Regards
Feldoh

Comment: It clearly says that you are missing the antlr jar dependencies. So you must add it to your classpath. The command is sth like javac -cp(or -classpath) directory/antlr.jar

Comment: Also another possible issue is that there are a lot more class files than this but these are the only .java files as there are a lot of inner classes in the autogenerated stuff.

Comment: tried setting "JFLAGS = -g -cp /home/Feldoh/src/antlr-3.2.jar" this does not seem to have helped. The same errors still appear now the error looks like javac -g -cp /home/Feldoh/src/antlr-3.2.jar src/Package1/1.java org.antlr.runtime does not exist

Comment: You missed the no absolute paths mantra.

Comment: Also tried setting JAVAC = javac -cp /home/Feldoh/src/antlr-3.2.jar this did not help either.

Comment: Put jar in same dir as makefile then replaced "javac -cp /home/Feldoh/src/antlr-3.2.jar" with "javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar" this has removed a lot of the errors it went from 28 to 6.

Comment: Con you compile/run without errors from the command line (i.e. without using a makefile)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a few issues here:

- as described you need to setup the Blaise class in the default package in the root directory of the tar file
- any packages you use, should also be present directly under the root directory, not in a source sub-directory (as Java/Javac will not be able to find them there)
- make is specific wrt where you use space and tab characters
- your makefile does not use options to the javac command
- which version of make are you trying to build a makefile for? the version I know would take a format like:

  ```
  JAVAC = javac
  JAVACFLAGS =
  SRC= Blaise.java \
      package1/1.java \
      packageA/2.java
  CLS= $(SRC:.java=.class)

  all:  $(CLS)


  .SUFFIXES : .class .java
  .java.class :
      $(JAVAC) $(JAVACFLAGS) $<
  ```

Comment: the makefile will need to compile the packages as well so I am not sure if this will work. Am trying now.

Comment: @feldoh, your package classes should be defined in the SRC variable too, see the edit for an example how to.

Comment: It starts compiling but errors it goes like this. 1 2 3 where 1 is a series of successfully compiled java files, 2 is Eval.java and 3 is a subsequent file to compile. 3 implements Eval and errors when compiling complaining that it cant find Eval.class despite the fact that Eval was already compiled before it and that Eval is in the same folder as the 3. There are many such classes and it does not matter how I reorder the files it cannot get past the first file which implements Eval. It still compiles fine in Eclipse though.

Comment: The problem is that it cant seem to import things in its own package is there some special way of doing this.

Comment: You should put the .java files in a folder as named by their package. I.e. a.b.A.java goes in the folder a/b under your root directory. The quickest way to test is to just run javac from the command line to compile Blaise.java and see if javac auto-compiles the other files or raises a warning. Relocate .java files into their package folders under the root until javac succeeds.

Comment: I managed to get everything into the default_package in eclipse without breaking it. So there should be no packages but still it says it cant find symbol Eval and package Eval at various points in the code of Blaise.java on compiling even with javac. But if that is the case how can it work fine in eclipse.

Comment: In eclipse you can rebuild the whole project to check for lingering information. Also if you have a separate bin folder in your eclipse project have a look at the .class files in there and the folders they are in relative to the bin folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a classpath which does not include the current directory, make sure you indicate a source path, too.

```
JAVAC = javac
CLASS_FILES = src/package1/1.class auto-generated/packageA/2.class auto-generated/packageA/3.class auto-generated/packageA/4.class src/Package2/5.class src/Package2/6.class src/Package2/7.class src/Package2/8.class src/Package2/9.class src/Package2/10.class src/Package2/11.class src/Package2/12.class

CLASSPATH = antlr-3.2.jar
SOURCEPATH = .

Default: $(CLASS_FILES)

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) -classpath $(CLASSPATH) -sourcepath $(SOURCEPATH) $<

clean: $(RM) *.class
```

The alternative would be using a classpath which includes the current directory (since the classpath is used, when you give no sourcepath):

```
CLASSPATH = .:antlr-3.2.jar

%.class: %.java
    $(JAVAC) -classpath $(CLASSPATH) $<
```

(the rest as above)

Of course, you could add the options to the `JAVAC` variable, too.

Answer (score 0):

Fix up your javac call by adding antlr to the classpath. I really despised the automated marking scripts my CS professors used. They stochastically failed based on submission load. [Here](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html) is a nice intro to Java and Makefiles. Basically try to glob your .java and .class files. Use the JFLAGS to pass antlr in the [classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html#options).